# How to progammicaly open context menu?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I need to open context menu in oncreate method. 
What I do:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cont = new CustomViewContainer(this);
        setContentView(cont);

        this.openContextMenu(cont);
    }
    @Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "a");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "b");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "c");  
    }
}
```

But so I don't see the menu. Help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the `openContextMenu(View)` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29), you must call [`registerForContextMenu(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) first:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    cont = new CustomViewContainer(this);
    setContentView(cont);

    registerForContextMenu(cont);
    openContextMenu(cont);
}
```

Comment: I see Exception: Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: Oh, just add onWindowFocusChanged and all is fine

Comment: where to add onWindowFocusChanged ? @Leo

Comment: I am facing similar issue but where to add onWindowFocusChanged ?and what should be passed to onWindowFocusChanged? True or False?  @Leo

Comment: @AnujKumarJha It was a long time ago.. Perhaps you need to put openContextMenu(cont); into onWindowFocusChanged method. More: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)